# Data Access Application Block for .NET 4.5 using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, enterprise-library

I'm trying to develop an application using MVC 4.
Earlier I was using Generic repository for accessing my database .
But later I was suggested to use `Data Access Application Block` to access Data Base in my application .

I'm not getting any exact clue that how to start with it.
Can any one suggest some link which can provide me the exact information about Data Access Application blocks for .NET 4.5 and MVC 4 and also some examples of its correct usage.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: @scott4dev Please provide some more information about it or any link which can provide the same..

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Data Access Application Block is quite obsolete.

Why don't you use an ORM (such as Entity Framework or NHibernate) to build your data access layer? As you can see [here Entity Framework is Microsoft’s recommended data access technology for new applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a lot of documentation on the Pattern & Practices site at MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440726(v=pandp.60).aspx.

I have used DAAB in a few projects, but it's quite heavyweight and isn't as widely used as other frameworks. It's also very data-centric rather than being more domain oriented. You might want to consider Entity Framework or a similar ORM over DAAB.